# Multiple location configuration under single server

Tags: nginx

I have two virtual directories(portal1 and portal2) both serving static content. Here is my nginx configuration. For some reason its not taking anything other than / under location. Any thoughts what Im missing ?

```
worker_process 1;
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
   include mime.types;
    sendfile on;
    server {
      listen 95;
      server_name localhost;
      location /portal1 {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html/portal1;
          index index.html;
      }

      location /portal2 {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html/portal2;
          index index.html;
      }



    }
}
```

I'm trying to access the URLs :

localhost:95/portal1
localhost:95/portal2

I keep getting 404 not found for both of them.

Comment: The path to the file is calculated by concatenating the value of `root` with the URI, so the URI `/portal1/foo.html` will be expected at `/usr/share/nginx/html/portal1/portal1/foo.html`. Use: `root /usr/share/nginx/html;`.

Comment: I made the changes to the nginx.conf as below..The webpage at http://localhost/portal1/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    include    mime.types;
    sendfile on;
    server {
  listen 95;
  server_name localhost;
  
  location /{
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   index index.html;
  }
  location /portal1{
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   index index.html;
  }
    
    }
}